# Criar novas Rows no Bootstrap de acordo com a quantidade de itens no banco de dados com PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, foreach

Preciso criar uma nova `div class="row"` quando atingir o limite de 12 colunas, no meu caso eu estou utilizando `col-md-3`. Portanto, o máximo de itens por coluna são 4.

```php
<?php foreach ($data['palettes'] as $row): ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="view-palette shadow p-3 mb-5 rounded clearfix">
            <div class="palette">
                <div class="spot color-1" style="background-color: #<?=$row->color1?> !important;"></div>
                <div class="spot color-2" style="background-color: #<?=$row->color2?> !important;"></div>
                <div class="spot color-3" style="background-color: #<?=$row->color3?> !important;"></div>
                <div class="spot color-4" style="background-color: #<?=$row->color4?> !important;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mt-3">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">
                    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> 0
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

*A variável `$data` só está recebendo os dados do banco `return $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM palettes");`*

Só que dessa maneira que eu fiz, está criando uma `.row` pra cada resultado que está vindo do banco de dados. Como resolvo isso ?

Comment: E se remover a `div` com a classe `row` do laço e usar `flexbox` ? No caso criaria uma `div` fora do laço com as propriedades: `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: E as colunas ficaria como? Eu ainda estou aprendendo :(

Comment: Mantendo o `col-md-3` no item, o `flexbox` irá organizar automaticamente sem a necessidade da `class row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o loop dentro do `<div class="row">` e use a classe `form-group` `<div class="col-md-3 form-group">` para adicionar um espaço entre as colunas quando e não couber na mesma row.

**Exemplo:**

```
<div class="row">
<?php foreach ($data['palettes'] as $row): ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <div class="view-palette shadow p-3 mb-5 rounded clearfix">
            <div class="palette">
                <div class="spot color-1" style="background-color: #<?=$row->color1?> !important;"></div>
                <div class="spot color-2" style="background-color: #<?=$row->color2?> !important;"></div>
                <div class="spot color-3" style="background-color: #<?=$row->color3?> !important;"></div>
                <div class="spot color-4" style="background-color: #<?=$row->color4?> !important;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="float-left mt-3">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-sm">
                    <i class="fas fa-heart"></i> 0
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

Muito simples: o seu `foreach` está no local errado. A `div` row ela cria uma nova linha e dentro dessa linha conterá os elementos, entāo o seu `foreach` deve ser colocado dentro da `div.row` antes da `div.col-md-3`

Comment: Mas uma `row` suporta até 12 colunas, nesse caso irá criar várias colunas de `col-md-3`, vai extrapolar a `row`

Comment: isso mesmo, porém quantos registro haverá no seu banco de dados ?

Comment: você pode limitar sua consulta no banco de dados...  dessa forma virá sempre 4

Comment: O tanto que tiver, é ilimitado saca?

Comment: sim..isso mesmo, deixa eu ver se eu entendi sua necessidade você vai cadastrar varias vezes porem nessa pagina voce irá mostrar sempre os 4 últimos cadastrados ? ou irá mostrar todos os registro cadastrados ?

Comment: Tipo... Vou sempre mostrar TUDO, só que quando atingir o limite de 4 colunas de 3 dentro de ROW, ele cria uma nova ROW

Comment: Entendi.. entāo acredito que o bootstrap por si só já resolvei no caso quando voce fazer o foreach ele vai pegar o quinto elemento e jogar para linha.. já tentou fazer o foreach dentro da div.row ?

Comment: Já sim, o jeito é utilizar, display flex msm igual o mano ali citou

Comment: Sim...  Se voce realmente precisa de que seja criado uma row nova entao terá que ser o display flex mesmo